# Implementing a 3D Minimap for VR in Unreal Engine

Tags: camera, unreal-engine4, virtual-reality

I am working on a VR tower defense game. I want to place my towers on a small map of the field and at the same time show the field/units/towers on the small map, in 3D. Like this: 
http://halo.bungie.net/images/games/Halo3ODST/imagery/screenshots/H3ODST_PreparetoDropCinematic.jpg

The map would be something like a small clone of the field. Is there a way to do so with camera etc. So that my minimap is just a re-render/clone of the field.

Sorry if this is the wrong place, but the Unreal Engine Forum is not working at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of a simple camera projection to 3D (since the camera map would be about scene capture onto 2D textures)

You can do a fake/tricky camera implementation tho. You just show a normal camera projection and put it into the world. Now you let the actual camera position depend on where the users location is in relation to the map.

You can cover this up with particle effects so it doesnt look like some TV that is following you....

---

depending on the complexity of your game and how u like the solution obove it might be better to implement a calculated model.

Like you have miniature models of everything u want to show on the map and then let a map class project every "object that is shown on map" the miniature version onto the map object.

Ofc this requires tons of work compared to just setting up a camera but you have alot of better control of how the map looks and what it can do (u could add functionallity, control options and special views etc....)